# Text is not entered completely with sendKeys in Chrome Browser when running on amazon Ec2 ubuntu machine

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

When connceted to ec2 ubuntu machine using VNC viewer, and running my java selenium script text is not getting entered completely using **SendKeys** for chrome browser.

```
Ex:
a)403567, its entering only 4035
b)Shirt123456, its entering only shirt12
```

For firefox browser its working fine.
In my local machine (Mac OS) also selenium script is working fine for both chrome and firefox browser

Comment: Check version of all components (browser, driver, jars). Clean and rebuild your project. In case of persistence add page url or it's source code and your test code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it didn't help.

Comment: Looks to be there is an issue with sendKeys() method and Chromedriver for Ubuntu OS

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved with argument type of Javascript Executor. Instead os sendKeys() used this method which resolved issue. Now text entered completely

webElement txtEle = driver.findElement(By.className("SearchInput"));
String ProductId = "5986742";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + ProductId + "';", txtEle);